# How to make some fields optional in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've coded a function that signs up a user. In my sterilizer the name field is optional but whenever I try to create a user without giving a name, I just face `KeyError: 'name'`.
what should I do to make this code work?

```py
def post(self, request):
        if request.user.is_anonymous:
            data = RegisterationSerializer(data=request.data)
            if data.is_valid():
                User.objects.create_user(email=data.validated_data['email'], username=data.validated_data['username'],
                 password=data.validated_data['password'], name=data.validated_data['name'])    
                return Response({
                "message": f'{data.validated_data["email"]} account was created successfully'
                }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            
            else:
                return Response(data.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response({
                "message": "You already authorized"
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to access to `name` in your validated_data. But there is no name.

you can do something like `User.objects.create_user(**data.validated_data)`
or you can do

```py
User.objects.create_user(
        email=data.validated_data['email'], 
        username=data.validated_data['username'],
        password=data.validated_data['password'], 
        name=data.validated_data['name'] if 'name' in data.validated_data else '') # or None
```

Comment: the **data.validated_data includes repeated_password which raise TypeError: create_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'repeated_password' how can I post it without repeated_password?

Comment: let's say you have `validated_data = data.validated_data` you can `del validated_data[key]` in order to remove it for example (before doing **validated_data ofc).

Comment: `validated_data = data.validated_data del(validated_data["repeated_password"]) User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)` now with this the code is woriking thank you!